# Computer Algebra Systems that support variable sized matrices

Tags: matrices, computer-algebra

I'm familiar with sympy, the matlab symbolic package, reduce, and have tried out a few other computer algebra systems. However, as far as I can tell, none of them seem to be able to do algebra on variable sized matrices - they can only work with fixed sized matrices.

Are there any that can do algebra for variable sized matrices? I understand there would be quite a few gross cases but I feel like there is a significant amount that is doable simply because of the ease of many simplifications/algebra one can do by hand in with matrices in R^nxn.

It is possible to just work with non-communiative algebraic elements in many of these, and so that covers addition and Hadamard product with matrices, which is useful and a start. However it covers a very small portion of what one actually does with matrices (say, transpose, inverses, eigenvalue decomposition, using matrices in R^nxm, etc.). Does any more general software exist?

(this question is reposted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33837544/computer-algebra-systems-that-support-variable-sized-matrices) because mathoverflow seemed like a more appropriate place to ask this question)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708208/symbolic-matrices-in-mathematica-with-unknown-dimensions

Comment: You might consider adding a top-level tag in order to make more people see this question.

Comment: What do you want to do with the software?  It seems to me any software that can deal with fixed dimension matrices can more or less tautologically deal with arbitrary-sized matrices.  In C++ or Python you could easily code-up such routines.  But what would you want to do with them?

Comment: Ideally I would like a way to have an input optimization problem (in terms of the minimization function and contraints described by matrices), and be able to transform it to a problem that is already known how to solve, or at least simplify it, and automatically generate the dual problem and perhaps compute the duality gap. Optimization problems typically are n-dimensional and it's usually nice to have a general form that is independent of dimension for a given problem.

Comment: I understand that some of those steps are non-trivial, so I'm really just wondering what software exists so I don't have to reinvent the wheel as much as possible and instead focus on the more interesting problems here such as reductions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SymPy has a [matrix expressions](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/expressions.html) module that does this. Example:

```
>>> from sympy import MatrixSymbol, Matrix, symbols
>>> n, m = symbols('n m', integer=True)
>>> X = MatrixSymbol('X', n, m)
>>> Y = MatrixSymbol('Y', m, n)
>>> (X*Y).T
Y'*X'
```

Matrix expressions can have symbolic sizes (like `n` and `m`) or explicit integer sizes, in which case they can be combined with explicit matrices.

It's also worth noting that there are a lot of things that aren't documented in the doc page I linked to, so take a look at https://github.com/sympy/sympy/tree/master/sympy/matrices/expressions for the full functionality.

You can also look at this [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nVt24G_2VC0) which uses this module, along with some modules that are separate from SymPy.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what precisely you are looking for, but the [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org)
package [MatricesForHomalg](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/matricesforhomalg.html) provides elaborate functionality for
dealing with matrices in the context of homological algebra.
This package is part of the [homalg project](http://homalg.math.rwth-aachen.de/index.php/) which is a larger
open source software project for constructive homological algebra.